# Extract unique lines from file with duplicated lines

Tags: bash, text, unique

I want to extract only the lines that are unique. For example if the sorted file has

```
dog
dog
weasel
cat
cat
skunk
turtle
turtle
```

I want to extract

```
weasel
skunk
```

Everything I have found (for example `uniq -u`) would produce

```
dog
weasel
cat
skunk
turtle
```

That is not what I want

I have spent some hours searching google and only find commands to eliminate duplicate lines and none to extract unique lines.

Comment: Actually the information is not on a single line.  I entered the words on individual lines and don't know how they got compress onto a single line.  Actually I have about 300 lines some that are duplicated and some that are unique.  I want all the unique ones.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
echo 'dog dog weasel cat cat skunk turtle turtle' | tr ' ' "\n" | uniq -c | grep ' 1 '
```

Will give

```
      1 weasel
      1 skunk
```

With some `cut` text-fu you can retrieve the names only, *e.g.*

```bsh
echo 'dog dog weasel cat cat skunk turtle turtle' | \
  tr ' ' "\n" | \
  uniq -c | \
  grep ' 1 ' | \
  cut -d'1' -f2 | cut -c 2
```

Will give

```
weasel
skunk
```

Comment: The edit brings the order of the terms back to the way I entered them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your real file has all the duplicates grouped together like your sample does:

```
uniq -c input.txt | awk '$1 == 1 { print $2 }'
```

should do it.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!